# Groovy - How to provide relative path to a input file when it is placed in the directory 2 nodes before the Project path

Tags: groovy, soapui, relative-path

Im using `SOAPUI 5.2.1` free version and my test suites are placed in Git. SOAPUI Test suites can be pulled by any one in the organisation and when they try to run the test, execution is aborted saying "File not found" exception as the path provided is local to my system

Test scenario - Import test data from csv

Input file location will be - 2 directory ahead of the Project path (retrieved using groovyUtils.projectPath)

Example:

SOAP UI test case (.xml file) location - **C:\Tester\Demo\Day1\Login-soapui-project.xml**

Input file location - **C:\Tester\Test-data.csv**

How to provide relative path in the groovy script for accessing the Input file

**UPDATE:** Adding the script that is being used from the comment

```groovy
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context) 
def projectDir = groovyUtils.projectPath 
File file = new File(projectDir) 
def firstLevelDir = file.getParent()
```

Comment: What do you have now that is not working?

Comment: I tried with absolute path only and not sure about how to provide the relative path in this scenario. And above is just an example. There are more than 400 test suites, where the input file will be always placed 2 folders ahead of soapui-project.xml file (i.e path (retrieved using groovyUtils.projectPath))

Comment: @Tester, can you please show the relevant script code which access the files?

Comment: Thanks - Got the answer. Used the below code. {def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def projectDir = groovyUtils.projectPath     File file = new File(projectDir)
def firstLevelDir = file.getParent()